# Is there a config value in Wine to force Enter to send CR+LF?

Tags: linux, wine, newlines

I'm pretty new to Wine and I'm trying to use an IM client which is required for my work.  When I hit 'Enter' to send a chat message, the characters indicating a new line are not being correctly interpreted.  Here's a basic SYN-ACK between the two of us using this IM client:

His view (on Windows):

> me: SYN!him: ACK!

My view (on Linux via Wine):

> him: SYN!me: ACK!me: ACK!

Is there any way I can configure Wine to handle this correctly?  Please note: this is a required application and I have no way to change its configuration.

Comment: And this is why I don't pretend to be able to write my own protocols.

Comment: I updated this to be a little more specific: I'm *not* writing a chat client.  The SYN-ACK is just to show what happens on each of our screens when we are communicating.

Comment: I understand. What I'm saying is that the IM client misimplemented a custom protocol.

Comment: Ahh, gotcha.  Sorry, I thought my question wasn't quite clear :)

Comment: Good question, but I might be inclined to try a different (linux native?) client that can interact properly with my coworkers...

Comment: @Dave, I would love to, but I don't know of any clients which are inter-operable with it.  This is a required client by our department.